# php calculator switching multiplier based on input

Tags: php

Hello I am building a simple computer in php.
It should work in the way that when the user selects number greater than 30, the variable ( in this case m1 ) becomes m2 and so on.
How can i accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

```
<?php
    $m1 = 5 /*prezzo della  maglia -  price 1*/;
    $m2 = 2;/*price   when quantity is over a number*/
    $m3 = 1;/*price   when quantity is over a number*/

    $s1 = 3; /*price of print 1*/
    $s1 = 3; /*price of print 1 if quantity change*/

    $bxs = $_GET['bxs'];
    $bs = $_GET['bs'];
    $bm = $_GET['bm'];
    $bl = $_GET['bl'];
    $bxl = $_GET['bxl'];
    $b2xl = $_GET['b2xl'];
    /*riga del nero*/
    $nxs = $_GET['nxs'];
    $ns = $_GET['ns'];
    $nm = $_GET['nm'];
    $nl = $_GET['nl'];
    $nxl = $_GET['nxl'];
    $n2xl = $_GET['n2xl'];

$somma = $m1*($bxs+$bs+$bm+$bl+$bxl+$b2xl+$nxs+$ns+$nm+$nl+$nxl+$n2xl);
?>
```

Comment: how user could select the value?

Comment: this is my html for the test [link] (http://creami.altervista.org/) does not look at the table little , love going in the user enters the values ​​in the table then the price according to the total number , meaning if any table contains 100 pieces will have the price for 100

Comment: not clear what you want to reach. I presented you the if statement, the buisness login is on your side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is simple, but you must provide the user way enter that value.

For example by the GET parameter `number`
    `$userInput = $_GET['number'];`

Then you only need to create basic if statement. You can read about it at http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

```
$somma = $bxs+$bs+$bm+$bl+$bxl+$b2xl+$nxs+$ns+$nm+$nl+$nxl+$n2xl;
if($userInput <= 30){
    $somma *=$m1;
}else if($userInput >30) {
    $somma *=$m2;
} else if($userInput > 8779){ // your number : )
    $somma *=$m3;
}
```

Comment: ho Seguito I Tuoi Consigli ma $ 3 ad esempio non viene calcolata ,mi sa che  e meglio farlo eseguire da js...